Why cats-effect memoize requires Concurrent instance?
I'd like to understand why memoize is exposed through Concurrent[F] in the Scala cats-effect library.
My intuition tells me that there should be no requirement for concurrency or fibers here and so be available for anything with Sync. As it's not the case, I would like to understand why.
I believe memoization might need a dedicated implementation in an asynchronous environment (where the second call might occur while the first one is still running and hence need to wait for the memoized result). However, is an asynchronous environment a hard pre-requisite? Or is it simply that alternative implementation could theoretically be provided for Sync but it has not been done (or justified) yet?

Are you sure you even need memoize, it is kind of weird and useless most of the time. Also, it seems you are in CE2 where Concurrent <: Sync, but in CE3 it is the opposite.

I need memoize from library perspective, I was looking for the least powerful bound I need for my type parameter to maximise the usefulness of the library.
I definitely need it though.

You may re-implement it using Ref, but not sure if that allows you a lower bound in CE2. - Another option may be to just use a var.
